# Mobile device capacity for sending SMS

Tags: android, ios, sms, windows-phone, smpp

Suppose I live in a country where I don't have access to any SMPP servers and all the typical sites for sending SMS (CardBoardFish, BulkSMS, Twilio, etc.) fail to send SMS in this country (because they don't have an updated database of "numbers and carriers").

I wan't to have a device (with either iOS, Android or Windows Phone) that is notified (with push notifications from a web application) for sending SMS bundles (an array of {recipient, message})

My questions are:

1. Is this a feasible solution?
2. Will it scale? One can put more devices when the rate is more than *X* sms/min
3. How many SMS can a mobile device send consecutively? Can it send for example 500 consecutively?

Comment: Your solution appears to be feasible, although you might get into trouble your mobile carrier. I can't answer the questions about scalability, but I do know that Android is probably the most suitable platform for a setup like this. With Windows Phone automating SMS is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is doable, though I'm not sure that doing it via a smartphone app is the best solution - there may be limits to push notifications, to what exactly an app is allowed to do in the background, etc. For example, WP apps' background tasks may not even run if the OS thinks that there's not enough resources (memory, CPU, etc.)

A more realistic solution would be to hook up a GSM modem or just an ordinary dumbphone to the server and send the messages through that. There is an opensource gateway software, [Kannel](http://kannel.org), that can be used to make any kind of connection, including the aforementioned SMPP and other protocol for other gateways, as well as a few for using devices directly. This way there's less moving parts and I don't know of any software restrictions.

Whether that will scale, is a different question. Most likely your mobile operator will just cut you off. Also, 500 SMS/sec. will not work with this setup. With most SMPP connections the throughput limit is significantly lower, and that is meant for setups where large amounts of messages are moved. A consumer device perhaps may be able to technically push out that much messages but the operator will probably throttle you or drop the messages.

One more thing, I find it weird that none of the larger SMS gateways wouldn't work since most of them do an HLR check for countries that have mobile number portability - that is, they check which network the phone belongs to, before sending anything.

Most mobile operators also provide direct connections to them, whether via SMPP or some other protocol but it generally is possible. Whether it's cost effective at your amounts, is a different question.

Comment: There is a software that does all what I said: ozekisms.com. Regarding the problem with the carriers in my country: they all require a VPN connection and a lot of burocracy to achieve the connection to their SMPP. Regarding the push notifications: this would be for bundle of SMS, not for each SMS (that could be 10 bundles per hour or so).

Comment: Yeah, carriers are like that almost everywhere, hence the comment about cost-effectiveness.